# Click event not firing after first click

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using jquerymobile 1.4.5

I have a series of radio buttons

```
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <legend>Condition (handles etc.):</legend>
          <input name="radio-choice-h-28" id="radio-choice-h-28a" value="1" type="radio">
          <label for="radio-choice-h-28a">Satisfactory</label>
          <input name="radio-choice-h-28" id="radio-choice-h-28b" value="2" type="radio">
          <label for="radio-choice-h-28b">Unsatisfactory</label>
          <input name="radio-choice-h-28" id="radio-choice-h-28c" value="0" type="radio">
          <label for="radio-choice-h-28c">Not Applicable</label>
        </fieldset>
```

and two buttons

```
  <form>
    <input id="set" data-inline="true" value="Save" type="button">
    <input id="reset" data-inline="true" value="Reset" type="button">
  </form>
```

The events are attached in the document ready area

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#set").click(function() {
$('#radio-choice-h-28a').attr("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
$('#radio-choice-h-28a').checkboxradio("refresh");
});

$("#reset").click(function () {
$("input[type='radio']").attr("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
});
});
</script>
```

I can set the value of the radio the first time through, and reset all the radio buttons the first time through.

When i click the set button the second time, nothing happens.
the second click of the reset also does not fire after the first click.

firebug does not show any error messages, but the breakpoint is hit each time the buttons are clicked (both set and reset)

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it....

I changed the attr to prop and now it works...

```
$("#radio-choice-h-28a").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$(document).on('click', "#set", function(){

});
```

Instead of

```
$("#set").click(function() { });
```

Comment: I replaced it as requested...   same result, the click event is seen, but nothing happens

Comment: Sorry, mis-understood your question. why are you using refresh?